# Order by a una expresión Query usando LinQ no se ordena de forma correcta

Tags: c#, linq

Quiero ordenar una secuencia por medio de su ultima palabra dentro de un array de tipo string, pero no logro entender porque mi Query Sintaxis no lo ordena de forma correcta.

Mi código:

```
string[] ArrayPostres = { "Pie de Manzana", "Pie de Limon", "Chocolate con Manzana", "Mermelada de limon", "Mermelada de pina", "Mermelada de Manzana", "Pie de pera", "Torta de Aguacate", "Mermelada de aguacate" };


IEnumerable<string> QueryPostres = (from x in ArrayPostres
                                    orderby x
                                    select x.Split().Last());

Console.WriteLine("_________________");

Console.WriteLine("Coleccion Original:");
foreach (var item in ArrayPostres)
{
    Console.WriteLine(">" + item);
}
Console.WriteLine("_________________");
Console.WriteLine("Colleccion con Split().Last():");
foreach (var item in QueryPostres)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-" + item);
}
Console.WriteLine("_________________");
```

Pero no siento que lo este ordenando de forma correcta.

Debería ir:

> Aguacate
> Aguante
> Manzana
> ...etc

Ósea, ¿ordenarlos de forma alfabética no?

Mi salida por consola:

> ```
> _________________
> Coleccion Original:
> >Pie de Manzana
> >Pie de Limon
> >Chocolate con Manzana
> >Mermelada de limon
> >Mermelada de pina
> >Mermelada de Manzana
> >Pie de pera
> >Torta de Aguacate
> >Mermelada de aguacate
> _________________
> Colleccion con Split().Last():
> -Manzana
> -aguacate
> -limon
> -Manzana
> -pina
> -Limon
> -Manzana
> -pera
> -Aguacate
> ```

Comment: eso... esta ordenado... lo que pasa es que solo te quedaste con la ultima palabra de cada item.. pero ordenaste por el item entero....

Comment: gbianchi, eso no está ordenado como lo pide el usuario, el ordena por el elemento completo y selecciona la última palabra del elemento, el usuario tiene que ordenar por la última palabra del elemento y seleccionar también por la última palabra del elemento, mira mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> QueryPostres = (from x in ArrayPostres
                                    orderby x.Split().Last()
                                    select x.Split().Last());
```

Aquí obtienes un **IEnumerable** que ordena tu colección por la última palabra del elemento recorrido del arreglo, la última palabra como bien pones en tu código la obtienes a través de la **función Split** que separa en **tokens** cada elemento del arreglo y posteriormente a través del **método Last** obtienes la última. Yo te recomiendo que en vez del **método Last** uses el **método LastOrDefault**, para evitar errores en caso de que haya un nulo.

El **método OrderBy** debes usarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
OrderBy x.Split().Last()
```

De esta forma se ordena por la última palabra.

Ahora bien si deseas eliminar los elementos duplicados ya que veo que en tu colección se repite por ejemplo la palabra manzana, usarías entonces el **método Distinct**. Quedaría así:

```
IEnumerable<string> QueryPostres = (from x in ArrayPostres 
                                    orderby x.Split().Last()
                                    select x.Split().Last()).Distinct();
```

De esta forma sale una colección ordenada por tu criterio sin elementos duplicados.

Comment: Incluye la explicación del código por favor :D

Answer (score 1):

Usa métodos extensores, solo seleccionas la ultima pablara, al tener el nuevo objeto, realizas un OrderBy de esta forma es mas sencillo y mas elegante, te quedaría una consulta así:

```
 var queryPostres =  ArrayPostres.Select(x=>newstring(x.Split().Last())).OrderBy(x => x);
```

Comment: Incluye la explicación del código por favor :D

Answer (score 0):

En esta espresión:

```
var QueryPostres = from x in ArrayPostres
                   orderby x
                   select x.Split().Last();
```

`x` corresponder a un item de `ArrayPostres` (Pie de Manzana, Pie de Limon, etc). Tu con `orderby x` estas diciendo que te ordene por ese `x` y que te seleccione `x.Split().Last()`, cuando lo que quieres es que también te orden por `x.Split().Last()` para esto puedes usar [let](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/walkthrough-writing-queries-linq#to-introduce-an-identifier-by-using-let) y de esta manera realizar la conversión (`Split().Last()`) con anterioridad al `select` permitiendo poder ordenar con él

```
var QueryPostres = from x in ArrayPostres
                    let item = x.Split().Last()
                    orderby item
                    select item;
```